# Are non-member operator overloads (specifically operator==) broken in Cython?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, operator-overloading, cython

I've got a use case I'm testing where, for performance, it's convenient to write a Cython wrapper class for C++'s `unordered_map<int, int>` type up front, then pass the wrapper to a bunch of Cython functions that use it, rather than always passing around Python `dict` (keyed and valued by Python `int`s that fit in C `int`) and converting on the fly over and over. I'm also trying to bake in some basic functionality to make it behave like a `dict` at the Python layer, so it can be worked with without converting en masse from Python `dict` to Cython `unordered_map<int, int>` wrapper and back.

My problem occurs in trying to implement `__eq__` efficiently in the simplest case (comparing one wrapper instance to another). AFAICT, in theory Cython's `libcpp.unordered_map` `pxd` definition pretends `unordered_map` has a member `operator==`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765908/364696) claims it should be fine, even though the `operator==` is actually a non-member function, since the definition only needs to exist so Cython knows it can just put a literal `==` in the code; the C++ compiler will look up the real overload when compiling the extension module.

But in practice, I can't seem to get it to work without additional manual (and hacky) intervention. For experimenting, I've just been using `ipython` `%%cython` magic. Right now what I'm doing is (minimized as much as possible while still exhibiting problem):

```
>>> %load_ext cython
>>> %%cython -+ --verbose --compile-args=/std:c++latest
... from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
... from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
... cdef extern from "<unordered_map>" namespace "std":
...     bint operator==(unordered_map[int, int]&, unordered_map[int, int]&)
... cdef class UII(object):
...     cdef unordered_map[int, int] c_map
...     def __cinit__(self, dict py_map):
...         cdef int k, v
...         for k, v in py_map.iteritems():
...             self.c_map[k] = v
...     def __eq__(UII self, other):
...         if isinstance(other, UII):
...             return self.c_map == (<UII>other).c_map
...         return NotImplemented
...
```

To be clear, this works right now, e.g.:

```
>>> pydict = {1:2, 3:4}; ui = UII(pydict); uieq = UII(pydict); uine = UII({1: 2, 4: 3})
>>> ui == uieq   # Compares equal for same value UIIs
True
>>> ui == uine   # Correctly determines different valued UII not-equal
False
```

but it *only* works because I included:

```
cdef extern from "<unordered_map>" namespace "std":
    bint operator==(unordered_map[int, int]&, unordered_map[int, int]&)
```

to explicitly define the non-member overload of `operator==` for the `<int, int>` template specifically (because Cython doesn't support generically templated functions, only generically templated classes and explicitly declared templates of functions). If I omit those lines, I get the following error from Cython:

```
[1/1] Cythonizing C:\Users\ShadowRanger\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_ea9bfadf105ac88c17e000476fd582dc.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        cdef int k, v
        for k, v in py_map.iteritems():
            self.c_map[k] = v
    def __eq__(UII self, other):
        if isinstance(other, UII):
            return self.c_map == (<UII>other).c_map
                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\ShadowRanger\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_ea9bfadf105ac88c17e000476fd582dc.pyx:13:30: Invalid types for '==' (unordered_map[int,int], unordered_map[int,int])
```

indicating that it believes there is no overload for `operator==` available. Am I doing something wrong that I can fix, or is Cython broken for non-member `operator==` (and possibly other non-member functions, despite what [this answer claims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765908/364696))? I *hate* explicitly defining every template specialization for non-member functions; it's not a huge burden for this specific case, but it seems odd that Cython would define member overloads, presumably to solve this specific problem, but not actually be able to use them. I checked the actual text of `unordered_map.pxd`, and it's definitely defined there:

```
cdef extern from "<unordered_map>" namespace "std" nogil:
    cdef cppclass unordered_map[T, U]:
        # ... irrelevant stuff expunged ...
        bint operator==(unordered_map&, unordered_map&)  # Looks properly defined...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are broken about Cython's handling of non-member operators:

1. Non-member operators defined in a .pxd file outside a class aren't correctly `cimport`ed to Cython (the workround is to do `from something cimport *`) and thus aren't used. This is what I think I said in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765908/364696)
2. <strike>Non-member operators defined within a class with two arguments (as in the code you showed in unordered_map.pxd) aren't recognised by Cython and aren't used *(despite being defined like that all over the C++ standard library wrappers included in Cython)*. At one point I tried to submit a patch for this but it was ignored.</strike> This is no longer true. Only point 1 now applies.

What does work is to tell Cython that it's a member operator (even if C++ implements it as a non-member operator). Therefore a simple patch to unordered_map.pxd would work. *Note that I'm changing it to be defined with one argument and the C++ implicit `this`/`self`*:

```
cdef extern from "<unordered_map>" namespace "std" nogil:
    cdef cppclass unordered_map[T, U]:
        # ... irrelevant stuff expunged ...
        bint operator==(unordered_map&)
```

Alternatively, you can define it yourself before you need to use it (like you're doing currently) but as a template. This at least saves you having to define every specialization

```
cdef extern from "<unordered_map>" namespace "std":
    bint operator==[R,S](unordered_map[R, S]&, unordered_map[R, S]&)
```

i.e. the statement in your question

> (because Cython doesn't support generically templated functions, only generically templated classes and explicitly declared templates of functions)

isn't true.

---

It is all a bit of a mess though

Comment: Ah, I had previously been looking for `std::move` support in Cython (which doesn't exist because [Cython breaks template type deduction in that case](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/-U8r0Lc_fU4)) and ran into (among other things) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29571780/364696), which asserted "Cython has no function templates" as the reason for declaring each specialization of `move`. But it looks like the problem is with Cython insisting on inserting the template type explicitly, which is a problem for `move`, but not for `operator==`. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I see you edited to note point #2 is no longer true. Looks like that means my original code now works without the explicit `cdef extern from "<unordered_map>" namespace "std": bint operator==(unordered_map[int, int]&, unordered_map[int, int]&) ` definition; if I'd tried this today, I wouldn't have need to ask the question. Do you have information on when this changed? It looks like it works for Python 3.9.5 with Cython 0.29.23, and clearly it wasn't working back in the 0.28.* timeframe, but I can't find anything obvious in the release history that talks about this fix.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't remember I'm afraid. I think it's at least been fixed for 2 or 3 years.